# Filters in SharePiont form based on answers

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I have a form in SharePoint which adds new items to list with questions about projects. In form user chooses project, tool and person that is assigned to specific tool. I want form to filter out options to choose based on previous answer: after choosing project, you can choose only tools in chosen project, and then person who is responsible for that tool - last one could be automated.

I checked that I could use PowerApps or InfoPath, but they are not supported in my company. The form works in Access, bot it needs to be transferred to / or rebuild in Sharepoint. I was thinking about using jQuery  but have no idea how to change rowsourse or filter out data using jQuery.

Comment: The term you're looking for is *cascading drop down* - here's some existing answers from SO: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsharepoint%5D+cascading+drop+down   Knowing the specific version of SharePoint will also help.

Comment: Please provide more details on this issue.